# InvokeManager not working in Q10 device

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades, blackberry-q10

I implemented **Email Composer/ Call Dial /Message Composer** using [Invoke Manager](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/device_platform/invocation/invoking_core_apps.html).

It is working fine in DevAplha device, Q10 simulator, Z10 simulator.

**Issue:**
It is not working in Q10 real device. I don't know what I did wrong. Anyone tried this in real **Q10 Alpha device**? 
Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the Device you have does not have the capability to make calls/send emails. Are you able to make calls with the device or is the phone button greyed out?